# What would be some approaches to get low noise images from cycles with given render time for indoor scenes?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light

For an animation of 10k frames I would like to find a tradeoff between render time and quality. With a given approximately render time of 1 minute per frame it would take 167 hours (a week, 24h per day) to render the full animation.

For outdoor scenes I simply increase the number of samples to achieve this.

For indoor scenes I use the *Limited Global Illumination* preset plus *Ambient Occlusion* and fiddle around the distance slider until the image looks 'bright enough'.

[image]

The lighting test scene has transparent windows, some emitting planes.

The results are:

with 50 samples (3 minutes):
[image]

with only 20 samples a lot more noise (~1 minute)
[image]

Which settings should be taken into account when trying to reduce noise for a given render time?

Completely different approaches are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce max bounces to 4(you don't need more), Use filter glossy to maximum. Use like 50-75 samples. Try to avoid using roughness(it makes a lot of noise). Make object Mix shader and put shader in bottom, than set the factor. There are a lot more suggestions which should help. 
[Here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Reducing_Noise)
are some more things to use.